# Same class loaded twice during start up of weblogic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, weblogic, classloader

Why is the same class loaded twice during WebLogic start up ?

Example: Log

```
[Loaded org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.**ResourceCondition** from file:/servers/cpq.server/tmp/_WL_user/cpq.server_cust_charge-dist-app/hn78jv/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.**ResourceCondition** from file:/servers/cpq.server/tmp/_WL_user/cpq.server_cust_charge-dist-app/hn78jv/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.**EhCacheCacheConfiguration$ConfigAvailableCondition** from file:/servers/cpq.server/tmp/_WL_user/cpq.server_cust_charge-dist-app/hn78jv/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.**EhCacheCacheConfiguration$ConfigAvailableCondition** from file:/servers/cpq.server/tmp/_WL_user/cpq.server_cust_charge-dist-app/hn78jv/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar]
```

Comment: Is it really being loaded twice or is it just logged twice?

Comment: how to check that @M.Deinum